# JSON.parse complains about "unexpected end of data"

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following code:

```
var default_links = 
'{ "name" : "Google",    "url": "https://encrypted.google.com/", "fav_url": "https://encrypted.google.com/favicon.ico" }\n'+
'{ "name" : "Yahoo",     "url": "http://www.yahoo.com/",         "fav_url": "http://www.yahoo.com/favicon.ico" }\n'+
'{ "name" : "GMail",     "url": "https://mail.google.com/",      "fav_url": "https://mail.google.com/favicon.ico" }\n'+
'{ "name" : "Twitter",   "url": "https://www.twitter.com/",      "fav_url": "https://www.twitter.com/favicon.ico" }\n'+
'{ "name" : "Facebook",  "url": "https://www.facebook.com/",     "fav_url": "https://www.facebook.com/favicon.ico" }\n'+
'{ "name" : "Wikipedia", "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/",     "fav_url": "http://en.wikipedia.com/favicon.ico" }\n';

function write_links()
{
    var linkdata = default_links.split("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < linkdata.length; i++)
    {
        var link = JSON.parse(linkdata[i]);
        document.getElementById("useful_links").innerHTML += '<a href=\"' + link.url + '"><img src="' + link.fav_url + '">' + link.name + '</a><br>';
    }
}
```

All the lines are parsed perfectly; but at the end, I find the following:

```
[xx:xx:xx.xxx] SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data @ http://127.0.0.1/homepage.html:33
```

What could cause this?

(I'm aware of the bad design: splitting over `\n` and all; I'm just doing that as a workaround for certain problems that need not be specified here.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a new line at the end of your last entry. This means that when you split on new lines, you have an empty string as the last item in your array. An empty string is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (i = 0; i < linkdata.length - 1; i++)
```

add -1 in for loop condition. split with newline will create empty array. so after run last loop it through error. we cant parse empty. otherwise remove last newline string in default_links

Comment: Then it will try to parse the item at index `-1`